# Can I read or save an open PDF in Adobe Reader with C#

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

The people at my work generate PDFs for trips in the logistical industry but they dont save them, they only print them out for drivers whilst it is open in Adobe. I am hoping there is a way to be able to either read the PDF whilst it is open in Adobe,or automatically save it too the HDD so I can open them with itext 7?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you running into issues? How does the file open in Adobe if it is not already on the computer?

Comment: Are you really talking about the Adobe Acrobat _Reader_ only? Or do you mean Adobe Acrobat, Adobe's software suite for creating PDFs?

Comment: The PDF that comes out of the logistics software opens up adobe reader so it can be printed and is in ram only so i dont have a path i can open up

Comment: If it opens in Adobe Reader, it's on a file system somewhere, I would have thought. Have you checked your temp directories as the file gets opened?

Comment: If you are able to print the file at least, you could consider using a virtual printer to save the print job. For example, the LEADTOOLS ePrint 6 has [Task Printers](https://www.eprintdriver.com/help/v6.0/Professional-Edition/#UsingTasksandTaskPrinters.htm) that can both route print jobs to the physical printer and save the PDF in the print job to the hard disk. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)